# ROR: MySQL query expression

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails

I have set up the Model, but I don't know how to write the code in controller to get result of the following SQL query..

```
 SELECT users.name, events.* FROM users, events WHERE users.id=events.uid
```

Thanks a lot.

I rename events.uid -> events.user_id

And set up the Model for both of them, attributes of events are

```
  t.integer :user_id
  t.string :title
  t.datetime :hold_time
  t.string :place
  t.text :description
```

And new error is 
`undefined method title for #<User:0x3fb04d8>`

Sorry for bothering you guys..

Comment: The answer by Jeff Paquette is quite right. As a minimum you should go through these 2 sets of documentation: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html and 
http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html

Comment: title is an attribute of Event, not user. You're calling it on a user object.

Comment: ok, I did wrong in view page. I should use "<%= e.events.title %>" instead of "<%= e.title %>". Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have set up your [associations](http://railsbrain.com/api/rails-2.3.2/doc/index.html?a=M001887&name=belongs_to) you should be able to do it like so:

```
u = Users.find(:all, :include => :events, :conditions => "users.id == events.uid")
```

Comment: I set up user Model for "has_many :events" AND event Model for "belongs_to :users". But it show up the error msg => undefined method `eq' for nil:NilClass. Why?

Comment: Can you rename events.uid to events.user_id ? that is the convention that rails uses for foreign keys. If not, you will need to specify :foreign_key => 'uid' on the Event's association, eg :belongs_to :users, :foreign_key => 'uid'. Can you post a stack trace for the undefined method call?

Comment: I got a new error.. and I edit the post for clearer description. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I cant comment yet (not enough rep), so I am posting an answer, but the:

```
"users.id == events.uid"
```

should be:

```
"users.id = events.uid"
```

I am not sure that will solve your problem, but it may.

if you want to find all users and events, you can do it like this:

```
users = User.all
users.each do |user|
  = user.name
  user.events.each do |event|
    = event.name
  end
end
```

and your models would look like this:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :events
end

class Event < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
end
```

I am sure there is another way to do it with event.uid, but I am not that advanced yet.

Comment: Thanks, I notice that too, because it will show up the SQL error. But I still get "undefined method `eq' for nil:NilClass"...

Comment: Are you trying to find the User and all their events?  If so, can you rename uid to user_id?  If that is true, I am editing my answer with the code you can use for that.  (I have no idea your knowledge of rails, so forgive me if I am explaining something too simple)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `find_by_sql` function to execute arbitrary SQL, so in your case you could do:

```
e = Event.find_by_sql( 'SELECT events.*, users.name as user_name from users, events where user.id = events.uid')
```

`e` would now contain all events with matching user names and you can access the user name just like any other attribute, e.g. `puts e.user_name`. Of course it is not possible to change the username since it was generated in a SQL query.

This approach may not be in accordance with Rails philosophy of DB agnostic applications, however I find that it is sometimes much easier (and probably faster) to use SQL directly instead of trying to achieve the same thing with ActiveRecord.

Comment: yeah.. I know I can just use find_by_sql.. but I also hope I can understand how to deal with those Model things. Anyway, thanks for your kindly help.